# Signing Sony Xperia theme

Tags: themes, signing, sony, sony-xperia

The themes which are made by sony officially work on non-rooted devices too...(probably signed by sony signer tool) 
But the themes made by me ( signed by google signer,needs rooted device)..they work but only the wallpaper changes.
Is there anyway to get the sony tool or how to make themes work completely even on non-rooted device?

Comment: I think from Android 4.4.2 you don't have to be rooted.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=51844829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make other stuff working, the only way I've found,

Is to :

```
* Sign each assets.
* Sign your APK
* Copy it into System App folder
* Change permission to rw-r--r--
* Restart phone.
```

But this works only on rooted phone.

I need to build a valid (good signed) package **too** !

Comment: I've contacted a theme designer and he confirms that the theme has to be signed by Sony...